# IE specific CSS not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Can someone help me why IE specific CSS is not working on IE?

Here is the link to live site:
http://www.themebia.com/pretavivre/

I'm trying to fix the top nav bars in IE. The nav bar looks good in Chrome and FF but not looking good in IE.

I've added appropriate below css fix for IE in the head of html.

```
<!--[if IE]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/css/ie.css"/>
        <![endif]-->
```

The ie.css is properly linked in head element but css is not working in IE.

You can reach the ie.css using http://www.themebia.com/pretavivre/wp-content/themes/pretAvivre/css/ie.css

NOTE: I've add firebug for IE, you have to right click a inspect the element.

Comment: Can you show the rendered source code?

Comment: Your missing the ; on the end of your bloginfo(); See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TARGET IE 10
http://suhasrathod.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/ie10-css-hacks/

`@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
         #yourDiv {margin-left:-570px;}
    }`

Answer (score 0):

What IE version are you using?

Conditional comments are supported from IE5 to IE9(inclusive), thus they won't work in IE10,IE11.

[**More on that**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: It should also be noted that one shouldn't *need* to give IE10/11 custom CSS anyways.

Comment: I'm using IE 11, Any help to fix for IE 11

Comment: @IrfanDayan why are you trying to write custom CSS just for IE11? IE11 should be a version of IE that can handle most all CSS correctly. Perhaps you can explain what you're tweaking just for IE and we can offer up alternative suggestions.

Comment: @DA, Will you please check my site link in FF and Chrome for top nav bars, It looks good but in IE 11 it get merged on each other?

Comment: @IrfanDayan Sorry, I don't do much with IE anymore so don't have IE11 handy to test with. That said, I'd suggest you post a separate question that describes that particular problem. It's likely an issue with your existing markup or CSS and if that can be fixed, you wouldn't need the extra CSS just for IE11.

Comment: I agree with @DA, IE10 and IE11 don't need custom `CSS`. Post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ie you are using?
If you test it on ie8, i am sorry to tell you that ie8 and earlier versions does not support :last-child.

Comment: I'm using IE 11, Any help to fix for IE 11.

Comment: try this
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none)
{
#menu-showroom li {  } /* IE10 */
*::-ms-backdrop, #menu-showroom li { } /* IE11 */
}

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you appear to be loading your IE CSS *before* all the rest of your CSS. The link appears to be working, but I'm assuming the rest of your CSS is over-writing your already declared CSS you loaded for IE.

The fix would be to move the IE CSS file to be the *last* CSS file loaded.

Comment: I'm using IE 11, Any help to fix for IE 11. Will you please add more detail to fix this for latest IE.

Comment: @IrfanDayan you shouldn't *have* to give IE11 separate CSS. Can you perhaps explain what the problem you're having with CSS in IE11 is?

Comment: Will you please check my site link in FF and Chrome for top nav bars, It looks good in FF & Chrome but in IE-11, it get merged on each other and disturb the alignment?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `;` on the end of your `bloginfo()`. However, the Wordpress Codex recommends using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` instead of `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');`.

Try this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/css/ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that IE 10 and up DO NOT support conditional comments at all.

Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 5 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 5.5 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 5.5000]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie55.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 5.5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Universal IE 6 CSS

```
<!--[if !IE 6]><!-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="REGULAR-STYLESHEET.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="REGULAR-STYLESHEET.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="http://universal-ie6-css.googlecode.com/files/ie6.0.3.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

[source](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

In style.css

change this

```
ul#menu-showroom {

  margin:0;

  padding:2px 0 !important;

}
```

and please let me know if it is working for upper navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely hate IE, specially versions 6, 7 and 8. When you are designing a wordpress theme, you have to style it twice, once for proper browsers and then for the IE ancients. The other big thing to remember, these ancients don't have support for media queries.

So to solve your problem, create a stylesheet called `ie.css`. You will use this to do all your styling for IE 7 and 8.

Next you will need to enqueue that stylesheet, but we will enqueue it conditionally. This stylesheet will only load for IE versions up to IE8. So in your functions.php, add the following

```
function enqueque_ie_stylesheet() {
// Load the Internet Explorer specific.  stylesheet.
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style-ie',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/ie.css',   array(), '' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'style-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ie_stylesheet' );
```

You can now add your styles in `ie.css`. Just remember to change `get_template_directory_uri` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` if you are using a child theme